# WPF: Ribbon control application button and quick access toolbar location

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, controls

How is the Application button and quick access toolbar placement accomplished?
[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Cc872782.Ribbon01(en-us,MSDN.10).png))</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first, put a reference to the Ribbon namespace in your xaml...

```
<r:RibbonWindow
        ...
    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        >
```

then you can configure your Application menu by binding to a RibbonCommand property on your ViewModel (much the same as you bind your other Ribbon commands)

```
<r:Ribbon>
    <r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <r:RibbonApplicationMenu
            Command="{Binding Path=ApplicationMenuCommand}">

        <!-- If your first menu item if 'Open File' -->
            <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem
                Command="{Binding Path=OpenFileCommand}" />

        </r:RibbonApplicationMenu>
    </r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
</r:Ribbon>
```

where the property looks something like:

```
public RibbonCommand OpenFileCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_openFileCommand == null)
        {
            _openFileCommand = new RibbonCommand("OpenFileCommand", typeof(RibbonApplicationMenuItem));
            _openFileCommand.LabelDescription = "Label Description";
            _openFileCommand.LabelTitle = "Label Title";
            _openFileCommand.ToolTipDescription = "Tooltip Description";
            _openFileCommand.ToolTipTitle = "Tooltip Title";

            _openFileCommand.CanExecute += (sender, e) => { e.CanExecute = true; };
            _openFileCommand.Executed += (sender, e) => { /* logic to open a file goes here... */; };
        }
        return _openFileCommand;
    }
}
```

For the second part of your question - I'm afraid I haven't played too much with the QuickAccess toolbar yet, but I'm guessing it will start with something like...

```
<r:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
    <r:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
     <!-- put your RibbonCommands here -->
    </r:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
</r:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `RibbonControl` is only displayed like that when part of a `RibbonWindow` which overrides the way the window's top frame is displayed. Basically, the `Application button`, `Quick access toolbar` and `Contextual tab` have a negative margin. However for this to work, the `RibbonControl` takes over the functionality that lets you move the window around with the mouse. Microsoft has released the `RibbonControl` as part of the WPF toolkit on codeplex, though its use has certain restrictions.

Comment: Thanks Klaus.  I'll go get the toolkit.